# phpStorm минимизация HTML

Tags: html, phpstorm, compression

Имеется ли в phpStorm возможность автоматической минимизации HTML файла, как это позволяет делать плагин «YUI Compressor JS»/CSS»?

Проблема в том, что без минимизации HTML файл весит больше и переносы строк в файле могут влиять на отображение страницы в браузере.

Comment: Лучше перепишите код так, чтобы переносы строк не влияли, а на вес вообще не смотрите, потому что на всех нормальных серверах есть gzip

Comment: Спасибо! Подскажите, тогда может есть встроенный инструмент/плагин позволяющий удалять из HTML файла хотя бы закомментированные строки? Чтобы не публиковались комментарии

Answer (score 4, accepted):

в PhpStorm нет встроенной автоматической минимизации HTML файла, но ее несложно добавить.

- `npm install html-minifier -g`
- в **Settings | Tools | File Watchers**, добавьте новый file watcher, используя custom шаблон
- в поле **Program**, укажите полный путь к html-minifier
- в поле **Arguments**, добавьте след. аргументы:

`$FileName$ --collapse-boolean-attributes --collapse-whitespace --html5 --remove-attribute-quotes --remove-comments  --remove-empty-attributes --remove-optional-tags  --remove-redundant-attributes --remove-script-type-attributes  --remove-style-link-type-attributes --remove-tag-whitespace --sort-attributes --sort-class-name --trim-custom-fragments  --use-short-doctype --minify-js -o $FileNameWithoutExtension$.min.html`

- в поле **Output paths to refresh**, укажите `$FileNameWithoutExtension$.min.html`
- **Working directory**: `$FileDir$`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Полный список опций html-notifier доступен по команде `html-minifier --help`. См. https://github.com/kangax/html-minifier

Comment: Спасибо! Все получилось - работает

Comment: Tip: If you want to show HTML files with the same name as nested, right-click on the Project tool Window and choose "File nesting...".
Add: Parent file suffix: .html -> Child file suffix: .min.html